# Error parsing xml: unbound prefix from com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="**************"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadOnCreate="true"
        android:id="@+id/adView"/>
```

I have this code here, with the xmlns:ads, but still getting the error of unbound prefix and Requires XML attribute "adsize" was missing.

Comment: Change to   `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment: Try removing the second `xmlns:ads` and leaving just: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment: error still exist @nKn

Comment: have you cleaned and rebuilt your project?

Comment: Can already thanks! @nKn

Answer (score 0):

In your case there are two xmlns:ads name space added.
remove xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads", and it will work.

I too had the same issue using the following xmlns, I could resolve the issue.

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Code for entire adview is below.

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
```